# Selenium: How to scan.in the getText() string

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can I `scan.in` the same text that I got from the `getText()` method?

When use the follwing code I get the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

```
public void Question()
    {

        //String a =scan.;
        String ques = d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='XYZ")).getText();
        System.out.println(ques);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(Sques);
        String a = scan.next();
        ((WebElement) d.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='XYZ']"))).sendKeys(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) two mistakes:

First, you're missing an apostrophe and a close bracket on the first **findElement**:

```
String ques = d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='XYZ")).getText();
```

should be:

```
WebElement elem = d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='XYZ']"));
String ques = elem.getText();
```

Also, your **sendKeys** line has **findElements** (plural) instead of **findElement** which returns a list array, hence the casting error.  You shouldn't need to re-locate the webelement anyway, since you've already got it in **elem** so the line:

```
((WebElement) d.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='XYZ']"))).sendKeys(a);
```

could be replaced with:

```
elem.sendKeys(a);
```

Comment: I cannot use **ques.sendKeys(a)** because **findElements** line has getText method and i dont want to getText again.

Comment: Ah, my bad...  Assign it to a WebElement type instead of a String on a different line.  Then you can just refer to the WebElement for both getText and sendKeys.  I'll fix my answer.